# Configure Doxygen to ignore the Source-Code Annotation Language (SAL)

Tags: c++, doxygen, sal

I have some classes that are documented with Doxygen. Additionally, they are annotated with Microsoft's Source-Code Annotation Language (SAL) to support static code analysis.

```
//! The majestic class.
class Foo {
    //! \brief do something
    //! \param [out] pResult The result value is stored here.
    //! \returns The return value Succcess indicates success.
    _Success_(return == Success)
    virtual Result_t DoSomething(_Out_ uint32_t *pResult) = 0;
};
```

In this case, Doxygen reports a warning:

> argument 'pResult' of command @param is not found in the argument list of Foo::_Success_(return==Success)=0

So, Doxygen is confused by the annotation statement `_Success_()`. 
How can I hide the return value annotation 
`_Success_(return == Success)` 
to Doxygen
without adding clutter to the source file? This does the job, but looks too verbose:

```
//! The majestic class.
class Foo {
    //! \brief do something
    //! \param [out] pResult The result value is stored here.
    //! \returns The return value Succcess indicates success.
    //! \cond INTERNAL
    _Success_(return == Success)
    //! \endcond
    virtual Result_t DoSomething(_Out_ uint32_t *pResult) = 0;
};
```

Can this be implemented by configuring Doxygen and leaving the source code untouched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the doxygen manual in the chapter `Preprocessing` there is a part:

> A typically example where some help from the preprocessor is needed is
>   when dealing with the language extension from Microsoft: `__declspec`.
>   The same goes for GNU's `__attribute__` extension. Here is an example
>   function.

In your case the following would probably work:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES
PREDEFINED = _Success_(x)=
```