# Using Microsoft's Source-Code Annotation Language (SAL) with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, doxygen, sal

I am trying to use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to document some C++ code that uses Microsoft's [Source-Code Annotation Language (SAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh916383(v=vs.110)). However, Doxygen does not parse certain annotation macros, like [`_Success_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh916383(v=vs.110)#example-the-success-annotation-in-combination-with-out), correctly. In the case of the example *function annotation*, `_Success_`, Doxygen misinterprets this macro as the function header/prototype.

Take the following example that contains the *function annotation* marker:

```
/**
 *    @file
 *    Example with function annotation.
 */

#include <windows.h>
#include <sal.h>

/**
 *    @brief This is a function.
 *    @param i a random variable
 *    @return TRUE on every call.
 */
_Success_(return) // The SAL function annotation.
BOOL function(_In_ int i) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

With the example above, Doxygen will interpret `_Success_()` as the function header/prototype and thereby, creates documentation that is absolutely wrong. Here is what the HTML Doxygen output appears like **with** and **without** the *function annotation*:

[image: Comparison with and without function annotation]

With the *function annotation*, Doxygen also says I have documented a parameter variable `i` that is not part of the list of arguments:

> C:/.../Source.cpp:9: warning: argument 'i' of command @param is not found in the argument list of *Success*(return)

Am I missing a configuration setting in the main [Doxygen configuration file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html)?
Or **is [SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh916383(v=vs.110)) and [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) simply just incompatible?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Ah ha!** After some further research, I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741626/configure-doxygen-to-ignore-source-code-annotation) on Stack Overflow that asked this same question, except it wasn't tagged correctly and did not explicitly say s/he was using "Microsoft's SAL." This is why it took me awhile to find it. *(I have updated the corresponding question to correct these missteps.)*

The [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741626/configure-doxygen-to-ignore-source-code-annotation#answer-51742120) references the Doxygen manual section entitled: *Preprocessing*.

> A typically example where some help from the preprocessor is needed is when dealing with the language extension from Microsoft: `__declspec`. The same goes for GNU's `__attribute__` extension. [...] When nothing is done, doxygen will be confused and see `__declspec` as some sort of function. [...]

Therefore, as pertaining to my example above, the settings that need to be configured in the [Doxygen configuration file](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html) are as follows:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = _Success_(x)= \
                         _In_=
```

Basically, this set of configurations means that the macros defined in the `PREDEFINED` section will be fully expanded and evaluated "*before the preprocessor [has] started*." But, these macros will expand to nothing as we provide "nothing" for the definition side of the equation (i.e. format: `name=definition`). Therefore, they are essentially ignored/removed while Doxygen builds the documentation documents.

**Unfortunately**, this does mean that one will need to continue to expand this `PREDEFINED` list to encapsulate, at least, all the SAL macros used in the source code. A better solution would to encapsulate all the SAL macros in this list, but future proofing is impossible as one will always be late at appending any *new* macros that are added later on. *But, at least, there is a solution!*